Normal curvature of a curve using fundamental forms
Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\varphi(u,v)=(u,v,0)$ and let $S=\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Find the normal curvature of a regular $C^\infty$ curve that pass through the point $p=\varphi(u_0,v_0)$ and has tangent vector in $p$ the vector $\varphi_u(u_0,v_0)$.
I have already demonstrated that $S$ is a regular surface, I calculated the first and second fundamental form at each point of $S$ and the various curvatures at each point of $S$ (it was asked for by the text of the exercise which I do not report entirely) . I don't know how to proceed for the normal curvature. Ok, here I have that $S$ is a plane and this might help me, but what can I say for a more complicated $S$ given a tangent vector $v$ which is linear combination of the first derivatives of $\varphi$?

What's the definition of normal curvature that you know?

Let $\alpha:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a regular $C^\infty$ curve. The normal curvature of $\alpha$ is the fuction $k_n :I\to \mathbb{R}, k_n(t)=\langle \alpha''(t), N(\alpha(t))\rangle$ where $N$ is the normal versor. It's the component along the normal versor of the curvature of $\alpha$.

So have you tried to do that calculation? What is $N$ in this case?

In this case, $N=(0,0,1)$ but how can I find $\alpha''(t)$ without an explicit expression for $\alpha(t)$?

Indeed, in this case $N$ is constant. So what do you know about $N'$? Think about this geometrically!

$N'$ is ortogonal to $N$ and so belongs to the plane spanned by $\varphi_u, \varphi_v$. I notice that the curve is surely planar, but then, what about it's normal curvature? Is it the norm of $N$?

If a particle moves in a plane, how much of its acceleration is normal to the plane?

I think it must be zero otherwise the particle leaves the plane

Now give a one-line mathematical solution to your problem.
